# Windows Xp can't detect sd card through data cable.

Tags: windows

I have been using widows xp since 2010.When i attach my android by data cable with pc.Though my pc shows phone memory but it doesn't show sd card.
What is the solution of it?

Comment: First, you should have upgraded ~2014. XP is no longer supported and is dangerous to have it connected to the internet. Second, newer Android versions use MTP/PTP, they don't expose the internal memory as a a mass storage device and in any case that is to be set in the phone itself.

Comment: Most likely solution lies within Antroid settings. Check if you have your SD card encrypted and if it is set up correctly as external storage.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia my new android phone shows the internal sd card as a mass storage device in windows...no configuration needed.

Comment: @Moab Is it running Android 4? I think that was the last version that did it. This article is from 2014: https://www.howtogeek.com/192732/android-usb-connections-explained-mtp-ptp-and-usb-mass-storage/

Comment: 8.00.371 is the version

Comment: @Moab Sorry, I completely forgot about this question. So you're running Oreo. You must have MTP/PTP. This is relevant for this question. The "old" way (up to 4) is supported by Win2000 and ME, it predates XP. The "new" way isn't supported but could be with https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19153 (if this *can't* be installed - I don't know - in expired Win versions shouldn't surprise anyone).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following ways:

**1. Assign / change drive letter for SD card.**

In Disk Management, check whether there is a drive letter for the card. Follow the steps below to add a drive letter:

Step 1. Right click “My Computer” and select “Disk Management”.

Step 2. In Disk Management, your SD card will appear as a removable disk. Check if it has a drive letter like D or E.

Step 3. If not, right click the SD card and select “Change Drive Letter and Paths”.

Step 4. Click “Add” and select a drive letter, then click “OK”.

Step 5. View if SD card can be detected.

**2. Turn Off USB Debugging.**

Step 1. Go to Phone System Settings -> Developer Options -> Turn Off USB Debugging.

Step 2. Connect your phone to your computer and open the USB data storage function.

Step 3. Check if the SD card can be detected.

**3. Clean our SD card.**

**4. Check our SD card in card reader.**

**5. Test our SD card in another PC or in another Mobile phone.**

**6. Remove SD Card Write Protection.**

There is a knowledge point that write protected SD card will not be displayed on other devices, except the original one. So if you did lock your SD card before, the first thing is to [remove write protection from SD card](https://www.gihosoft.com/data-recovery/remove-write-protection-sd-card.html). Check the lock switch beside the card or use disk utility.